# C# Constructor Problem When Using Generics

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, types

Please see an example of my code below:

**CODE UPDATED**

```
public class ScrollableCheckboxList
{
    public List<ScrollableCheckboxItem> listitems;

    public ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel>(IEnumerable<TModel> items, string valueField, string textField, string titleField) where TModel : class
    {
        listitems = new List<ScrollableCheckboxItem>();
        foreach (TModel item in items)
        {
            Type t = typeof(TModel);
            PropertyInfo[] props = new [] { t.GetProperty(textField), t.GetProperty(valueField), t.GetProperty(titleField) };
            listitems.Add(new ScrollableCheckboxItem
            {
                text = props[0].GetValue(item, null).ToString(),
                value = props[1].GetValue(item, null).ToString(),
                title = props[2].GetValue(item, null).ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Corrections to constructor declaration made! Still a problem with this code though

The code wont compile - it comes up with lots of strange little errors making me think that there's a design problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out you should drop the `void` keyword, however it is still not correct. The generic declaration should be on the class, not the constructor

```
public class ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel>
  where TModel : class
{
  public ScrollableCheckboxList(...) 
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of the function `ScrollableCheckboxList` is the same as your classname.

The error itself is correct, your code is not.

You want to declare a constructor, but by adding void before the name of the constructor the C# compiler thinks it's a function. And functions cannot have the same name as the class they live in (hence the error).

So remove `void` in front of the name of the function, then it will be a constructor.

And specify the `TModel` constraints at class level.

```
public /* void */ ScrollableCheckboxList /* <TModel> */(IEnumerable<TModel> items, string valueField, string textField, string titleField) /* where TModel : class */
```

Comment: I have updated the code above, it still wont compile and I dont understand why (with no definitive error from the compiler either!)

Comment: Ok, found the problem, the class declaration must define the generic object TModel, not the constructor. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEM FOUND**

The constructor may not declare the generic TModel definition, the class declaration must do that job

e.g.

```
public class ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel> where TModel : class
{ 
    public List<ScrollableCheckboxItem> listitems; 

    public ScrollableCheckboxList(IEnumerable<TModel> items, string valueField, string textField, string titleField)
    { 
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a constructor that takes generic parameters. You need to either move the generic param up to the class level or make the setting of items a method that takes a generic param.

```
public class ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    public List<ScrollableCheckboxItem> listitems;

    public ScrollableCheckboxList(IEnumerable<TModel> items, string valueField, string textField, string titleField)
    {
        listitems = new List<ScrollableCheckboxItem>();
        foreach (TModel item in items)
        {
            Type t = typeof(TModel);
            PropertyInfo[] props = new [] { t.GetProperty(textField), t.GetProperty(valueField), t.GetProperty(titleField) };
            listitems.Add(new ScrollableCheckboxItem
            {
                text = props[0].GetValue(item, null).ToString(),
                value = props[1].GetValue(item, null).ToString(),
                title = props[2].GetValue(item, null).ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

That should work fine, although I'd also recommend you don't expose the List member variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare a constructor. There's no `void` keyword in a constructor:

```
public ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel>(IEnumerable<TModel> items, string valueField, string textField, string titleField) where TModel : class {}
```

A type cannot contain methods that have the same name as the type.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a constructor, to be a constructor you've to remove the "void" keywork.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor has to be

```
public ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel>
```

rather than

```
public void ScrollableCheckboxList<TModel>
```

In other words, drop the void.